# SSH протокол стадии подключения

Tags: java, ssh

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться в последовательности установления ssh соединения с сервером. В учебных целях пишу программу на java подобие putty. Использую стандартные сокеты. Читал rfc 4251, 4252, 4253 Понял только до момента обмена версиями.

В чем собственно проблема. Отправляю на сервер на 22 порт запрос с версией протокола ssh. Сервер отвечает мне списком поддерживаемых алгоритмов шифрования.

Пишу пакет содержащий:

1. Длину всего пакета
2. Длину рандомных байтов
3. Метод обращения (20)
4. Сам список алгоритмов
5. Рандомные байты

В ответ получаю сообщение `packet corrupted`. Все.
Не могу разобраться Парюсь уже 2-е сутки. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина.

```
    public static void KEX_init(OutputStream os){
    String packet = null;
    int SSH_MSG_KEXINIT = 20;
    int packet_length = 0;
    int padding_length = 8;
    byte[] cookie = {1,6,2,3,4,5,2,3,7,6,2,3,4,1,6,5};
    String choise = "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, ssh-ed255";
    byte[] kex_alg = choise.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int kex_length = kex_alg.length;
    String encrypt_alg = "aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr";
    byte[] encr_alg = encrypt_alg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int encrLen = encr_alg.length;
    String encrypt_algs = "aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr";
    byte[] encr_algs = encrypt_alg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int encrLens = encr_alg.length;
    String mac_alg = "hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com";
    byte[] mac_algorythms = mac_alg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int macLen = mac_algorythms.length;
    String mac_alg1 = "hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com";
    byte[] mac_algorythms1 = mac_alg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int macLenS = mac_algorythms1.length;
    byte[] array = {(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0,};
    byte[] array1 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    byte[] padding = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int sum = cookie.length+kex_length+encrLen+encrLens+macLen+macLenS+array.length+array1.length+padding.length;
    try{
        os.write(sum);
        os.write(padding_length);
        os.write(SSH_MSG_KEXINIT);
        os.write(cookie);
        os.write(kex_length);
        os.write(kex_alg);
        os.write(encrLen);
        os.write(encr_alg);
        os.write(encrLens);
        os.write(encr_algs);
        os.write(macLen);
        os.write(mac_algorythms);
        os.write(macLenS);
        os.write(mac_algorythms1);
        os.write(array);
        os.write(array1);
        os.write(padding);
        os.flush();
    }catch(Exception e){}

}
```

}

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Вопрос не в самом коде. А в последовательности установления ssh соединения.

Comment: последовательность описана в упоминаемых вами rfc. ответ «packet corrupted» свидетельствует о том, что вы послали некорректно сформированный пакет. без минимального воспроизводимого примера ответить вам сможет разве что телепат.

Comment: Вас понял. Спасибо за разъяснение. Сейчас приведу пример пакета.

Comment: не пример пакета нужен, и даже не «пример» кода, а «минимальный самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример» (см. ссылку из первого комментария).

Comment: Добавил код. И проблему вроде описал.